# I cannot get access token from $_GET["code"]

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

I try to use google youtube api. Everything gone fine. I form client object like documents said. I redirect to youtube for permission and give permission. Then i take `$_GET["code"]`. But i cannot exchange it for access token.In `client -> authenticate` method , execution stop. Relative code snippet:

```
<?php

    require_once ('XXX/vendor/autoload.php');
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("AdKeek");
    $client->setAuthConfig('XXX/client_secrets.json');
    $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly");
    $redirect_uri = 'XXX THIS PAGE';
    $client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
    $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
          $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    }
    echo    '<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="padding-top: 10px;">
            <a href="'.$auth_url.'" style="border-radius: 5px;padding-left: inherit;padding-top: 5px;padding-bottom: 5px;width: 127px; display: block;" class="yutub" ><i class="fa fa-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span class="social-text">YouTube</span><i class="fa fa-link" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-left: 15px;"></i></a></div>';

?>
```

I read almost every document but i cannot find problem. What is the problem ???

Edit = I try this in my localhost. And it gives this error = GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL error 60

Comment: Are you sure `$_GET['code']` has a value?

Comment: Yes i wrote it in file and it is correct

Comment: link? i form a button and give auth_url in html code.

Comment: Looks like you expect a access token with the method `authenticate` but you need to retrieve the access token with the `getAccessToken` method:

`$access_token = $client->getAccessToken()`; read https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app

Comment: getAccessToken doesn't work and fetchaccesstoken doesn't work , i read it 10 times

Comment: In that case, your problem is your SSL certificate on your local host. Please refer to this document http://flwebsites.biz/posts/how-fix-curl-error-60-ssl-issue

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not following the authentication flow appropriately. After `$auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();` you have to be redirected to be authenticated and then you will get your access code. You have to use `header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));` Try using this code instead.

```
<?php

require_once ('XXX/vendor/autoload.php');
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("AdKeek");
$client->setAuthConfig('XXX/client_secrets.json');
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly");
$redirect_uri = 'XXX THIS PAGE';
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);

if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {

    $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();

    echo  '<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="padding-top: 10px;">
        <a href="'.$auth_url.'" style="border-radius: 5px;padding-left: inherit;padding-top: 5px;padding-bottom: 5px;width: 127px; display: block;" class="yutub" ><i class="fa fa-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <span class="social-text">YouTube</span><i class="fa fa-link" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-left: 15px;"></i></a></div>';

} else {

    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    //whatever else you want to do

}


?>
```

Now, if you already saved the access code, you don´t need to create an auth URL. Instead just grab the access code from the file and then use `$client->authenticate($code);` where $code = value from file.